# Is it possible to get the integer value of a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have a database query

```
SELECT Id FROM Phone WHERE Model = 'Droid'
```

that returns a table with one entry (because Id is a primary key). The table looks like this:

```
+----+
| Id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
```

Is there any way to get at that integer "1"? I'd like to use it in the following query, but it's generating a syntax error:

```
INSERT INTO Sale (Id, Price)
    VALUES (SELECT Id FROM Phone WHERE Model = 'Droid', 100.00);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
INSERT INTO Sale (Id, Price)
SELECT Id, 100.00 
  FROM Phone 
  WHERE Model = 'Droid';
```

Answer (score 1):

Subqueries need wrapped in their own `()`

Answer (score 1):

You simply need brackets around your select query like so:

```
INSERT INTO Sale (Id, Price)
VALUES ((SELECT Id FROM Phone WHERE Model = 'Droid'), 100.00);
```

That should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that you're getting some kind of type incompatibility; your syntax is just wrong.  Try simply

```
INSERT INTO Sale (Id, Price)
(SELECT Id,100 FROM Phone WHERE Model = 'Droid');
```